# Querying ArcGIS MapServer layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, map-service, search

I can add an ArcGIS map layer to my QGIS 2.18 project, or use the existing project provided by GeoNB (http://geonb.snb.ca/documents/misc/geonb_qgs.zip).  Using the identify tool, I can see features of different entities in each layer. For example, I can select a parcel from the parcels layer and it returns, among other things, a PID and an area.  I would like to be able to search within these layers to find the geometry I am looking for.  For example, I would like to be able to, knowing a PID, locate a geometry in my viewport.